# How do I get the ContentDistribution full url of an image?

Tags: url, content, website-integration, contentdistribution

We have images stored in Salesforce as ContentDocuments, and have generated **ContentDistribution** records for them in order to display them publicly in our portal and on our website (which is **Webflow** based).

The problem is that neither the **ContentDownloadUrl** or **DistributionPublicUrl** is in a format that Webflow will accept. The images display fine in our Salesforce portal and if opened directly in a browser (ie click on the link). What Webflow needs is the actual url that comes up from the ContentDownloadUrl being clicked it seems.

For example take this publicly available image (from our sandbox)
**ContentDownloadUrl**: https://syndex--qa--c.documentforce.com/sfc/dist/version/download/?oid=00D0k0000001V0M&ids=0680k000001QVQP&d=%2Fa%2F0k0000000ehb%2FrgjWFDHoTmJueiM8_2RdtCkcmxJpCaefBWhGDPUd0gs&asPdf=false

If the above link is clicked say from our Salesforce portal, the link below is generated, and this is the only one that Webflow will accept. I need to know how to get to this link in order to pass it to Webflow to display on our website.

https://syndex--qa--c.documentforce.com/sfc/dist/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Jpg&versionId=0680k000001QVQP&operationContext=DELIVERY&contentId=05T0k000004UreP&page=0&d=/a/0k0000000ehb/rgjWFDHoTmJueiM8_2RdtCkcmxJpCaefBWhGDPUd0gs&oid=00D0k0000001V0M&dpt=null&viewId=

Comment: What does `DistributionPublicUrl` look like? When I paste the `ContentDownloadUrl` into Chrome, it immediately downloads a JPG of a Land Rover

Comment: @cropredy it doesn't work either - we've tried both. The only one Webflow accepts is the long one from the downloaded image. (here's the DistributionPublicUrl, but it doesn't work in Webflow as I said https://syndex--qa.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/0k0000001V0M/a/0k0000000ehb/rgjWFDHoTmJueiM8_2RdtCkcmxJpCaefBWhGDPUd0gs)

Comment: i'd contact Webflow support; perhaps others have ideas. You could also try making a [ContentAsset public as per this help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000320130&type=1)

Comment: There is limit on how many downloads can happen via contentDownloadUrl per org. This limit may hit as it did in our case and we had to move our logic to using content assets.

Comment: @cropredy how would I access a ContentAsset file - doesn't that just use the same urls from a ContentDistribution? I can't find any urls on that object?

Comment: @prabuddhkumar do you have a link to documentation about these limits?